# Assign image position using javascript variables

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wish to change the position of my image depending on its size, so when its wider (as I will keep them the same height) it will stay central because its less left. Here is my code

```
    img1 = document.getElementById("type-pic1"); 
    width1 = img1.clientWidth;
    left1 = (300 - width1) / 2;
```

my div is 300 pixels wide. This is what I want my CSS to look like

```
    #type-pic1
    {
    position: absolute;
    left: var left 1;
    }
```

I don't mind doing this all in the javascript file, I hope this makes sense and someone can help, thanks in advance.

Comment: `img1.style.left = left1 + 'px';`

Comment: worked like a charm, thanks a lot, i must seem like a novice to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
img1.style.left = left1+"px";
```

Comment: worked like a charm, thanks a lot, i must seem like a novice to you